# SQL Ce- Query to return previous month does not work

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-ce

I used a query that somebody here on SO provided me with to get the results from the before currentdate, which works perfectly:

```
 WHERE IssuedOn >= DATEDIFF(D, 1, GETDATE()) and IssuedOn < DATEDIFF(D, 0, GETDATE()) ";
```

I though that for the previous month, changing D for M will be enough but obviously I am missing something:

```
 WHERE IssuedOn >= DATEDIFF(M, 1, GETDATE()) and IssuedOn < DATEDIFF(M, 0, GETDATE()) ";
```

This does not work. I need to return rows where IssuedOn is from previous month from current date.

Comment: By "previous month from current date", do you mean "a month ago from today" (i.e. Jan 7th, 2014 through Feb 7th, 2014) or "any time last month" (i.e. Jan 1st, 2014 through Jan 31st, 2014)?

Comment: Based on your responses to another answer below, it appears you mean the second one ("any time in the last month").

Comment: Sorry, yes - I  just mean when the number of month is current-1.

Comment: If that's the case, you should be able to plug the functions in my answer into your `WHERE` clause to get the appropriate range.  Hopefully the "long answer" is informative as to why your original attempt did not work, as well as why the `DAY` attempt did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The short answer:**

The following SQL will get the values for your date range:

```
 -- The beginning of the current month
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
-- The beginning of the previous month
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)
-- The beginning of the next month
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())+1, 0)
```

You can replace `MONTH` with any other [datepart](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) value to get date ranges for things like years, hours, days, etc...

**The long answer:**

The reason your days query worked but your months query did not is that SQL Server stores `DATETIME` objects as `FLOAT`s. The integer portion representing the date as days since 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 (hereafter referred to as "0"). The decimal portion representing the time (as a percentage of 24 hours).

If you call `DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())`, it will get the number of **days since "0"**, which basically is the same as converting the `FLOAT` representation of `GETDATE()` to an `INTEGER` representation (truncating the minutes and leaving you at 00:00).  For instance, if I run `SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)` today, I get "41675.3452306327".  If I run `SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())`, I get "41675".

If you call `DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())`, you will get the number of **months since "0"**.  Today, this gives me "1369".  If you try to compare that value to a `DATETIME`, it will simply convert "1369" to a `DATETIME`, treating it as "1369 days since 0" and result in a `DATETIME` of "1903-10-02 00:00:00.000".  To see this for yourself, try: `SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) AS DATETIME)`.

If you want to trim the days (and time-stamp) out of a `DATETIME`, you need to take the results of your `DATEDIFF` query and add it back to "0" with the `DATEDIFF` function, like so:

```
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

This basically takes date (to the month) and figures out how many months have passed since "0", then adds that number of months to "0".  In short, it returns a `DATETIME` that represents the beginning of the current month.

If you want to get the previous or next month, you can simply decrement or increment the value returned by the `DATEDIFF` function before passing it into the call to `DATEADD`, like so:

```
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())+1, 0) -- Get the next month
```

Comment: Thanks, its very detailed but I am not that skilled in SQL and not sure how to use that in my WHERE condition.

Comment: The different functions at the top (in the "short answer" section) can be used to retrieve the specific dates for your range.  Basically update your `WHERE` clause to check that `IssuedOn  >= "last month" AND IssuedOn < "this month"`.

Comment: Finally it is working, THANK YOU! Just a question, for the year, would it be the same just with Y?

Comment: **Yes, that is correct.**  I have a note on that in the bottom of the "short answer" that mentions that.  The above function calls can be used to "truncate" a date to any precision.

Comment: I feel really stupid, tried WHERE IssuedOn >= DATEADD(Y, DATEDIFF(Y, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) AND IssuedOn < DATEADD(Y, DATEDIFF(Y, 0, GETDATE()), 0)"; and for some reason, it shows me the current year instead :)

Comment: Try using the actual datepart constants such as `YEAR` instead of abbreviations like `Y`.  There's a link to the full list in the top of my answer.  The confusion arises because "Y" actually maps to "day of year", which I think ends up becoming just "day".  I didn't realize that "Y" mapped this way until you commented that it didn't work.